# AngularJS get value from <p> in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When the checkbox gets checked, I want to get retreive the value of the variable in my `<p>`tag to use it in my AngularJS.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{o.orderID}}" ng-change="stateChanged()"/>
<p id="orderID" ng-model="orderID">{{o.orderID}}</p>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
$scope.stateChanged = function () {
   var value1 = $scope.orderID;
    alert(value1);
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. How can this be accomplished fast and easy?

Comment: What is `$scope.status`? And you don't use `ng-model` with `<p>` tag.

Comment: should be $scope.orderID

Comment: could you add a fiddle to reproduce this?

Comment: You can't bind an ng-model to a <p> tag, ng-model works only with input controls: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: And you are doing value="{{o.orderID}}" in the input... where you probably want to do ng-model...

Comment: Ok, can I get the value of the checkbox then?

Comment: @Sesamzaad  does your check box is inside `ng-repeat`?

Comment: why you don't pass the orderID in the stateChanged(): ng-change="stateChanged(o.orderID)"

Comment: That's it! Fast and easy all i needed

Comment: @Sesamzaad do looked at answer I've added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your HTML is wrapped in a controller and your JS code is in definition of that controller function; change your method like this:

```
$scope.stateChanged = function () {
  var value1 = $scope.o.orderID;
  alert(value1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only can use `ng-model` on an input field. If you want to get the content of the `<p>{{o.orderID}}</p>`, you can call $scope.o.orderID.

If you want to query some content of an DOM element, you can use [angular jQlite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Answer (score 0):

Lets see, I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="o.orderID" ng-change="stateChanged()"/>
<p id="orderID">{{o.orderID}}</p>
```

Besides, I don't understand why you want to bind orderID to a checkbox... that will be a boolean value, either true or false. If we're talking about an *order id* shouldn't that be a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a variable in parent `scope` from `ng-repeat` div like `$parent.selectedOrder`, because ng-repeat creates a new scope while it is rendering DOM

```
<div ng-repeat="o in orders">
   <input type="checkbox" value="{{o.orderID}}" ng-change="stateChanged()"
    ng-click="$parent.selectedOrder = o.orderID"/>
</div>

<p id="orderID">{{selectedOrder}}</p>
```